# How do you set x and y axis and Title for a line chart using charts.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is using charts.js. This code only makes the line graph but the title, x axis and y axis does not show. I want to add title, and the names for those 2 axis onto the graph. what is wrong and how do you fix it? I also want to make the y axis to start from 0 and up.

```
async function chartDisplay() {
      await getData1();
      await getData2();
      const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
      const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: xLabels,
          datasets: [{
              data: ratingDataI,
              label: "data1",
              borderColor: "#3E95CD",
              fill: false
            },
            {
              data: ratingDataA,
              label: "data2",
              borderColor: "#3E95CD",
              fill: false
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
          },
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'label',
          },
          hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
          },
          scales: {
            x: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Dates'
              }
            }],
            y: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Value'
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the x and y should not be arrays but objects, also the `scaleLabel` prop is called `title` now. For all the changes please read the migration guide (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'yAxis'
        }
      },
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'xAxis'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: How would you add a range to the y axis

Comment: As the documentation states you can use the `beginAtZero` property: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-options, see updated answer